# how can add event on class hierarchy in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want the following structure

```
<div class="test">
<div class="test1"> 
</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to right down click event on test1

```
$(".test .test1").click(function()
{

 });
```

but it's not binding.

Any help?

Comment: is that your complete code?

Comment: Are the elements dynamically added to the DOM? Also is it right click you want or a normal click?

Comment: added how I added to jquery now edited to with function

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
$(".test .test1").click(function() {
     // Your code to handle when .test1 inside .test is clicked
});
```

or if you want to trigger click event on this element, then you can use `.trigger()`:

```
$(".test .test1").trigger('click');
```

Also, remember to add your code inside DOM ready handler:

```
$(function() {
    $(".test .test1").click(function() {
         // Your code here
    });
});
```

If your element are added dynamically to the DOM, you need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**:

```
$('body').on('click', '.test .test1' , function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: Did you try event delegation? check my answer.